# Nested variable substitution in spring boot config files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I need to fetch a property with the following format:

```
${/a/env/mode}
```

However this depends on where im deployed, I have all the required information in configuration already and is trying to use the following:

```
${/a/${env}/${mode}}
```

This is not working as expected in Spring Boot but instead gives an exception. Is there anyway to get what I need?

Comment: Why not just set the appropriate variable in the environment?

Comment: Not sure i understand. I have a custom PropertySource that need to lookup the value under the path from AWS parameterstore. So I first need to construct the correct path.

Comment: How about using profiles?

Comment: Yeah, profiles is is good option, it is flexible and avoid confusion also

Comment: We have over a 100 different combinations I would manually have to update with the ${/a/${env}/${mode}} stucture then. So if i dont missunderstand i would say that different configuration files for profiles is not an option

Comment: @user3139545 were you able to get a way through this ?

Comment: I made a variation, I have a custom PropertySource and then parse a path like this ${/a/<env>/<mode>} in code if the property start with a /. So I substitute env and mode in code instaed of relying on Spring Magic.